# Can you vs Can you maybe

Tags: difference

Is there any difference in meaning between these following sentences?

1. **Can you maybe** call him and tell him to meet us there?
2. **Can you** call him and tell him to meet us there?

Comment: The first one has one more additional word! *Just Kidding* :-). I would say, the first one is sort of less emphatic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A funny thing in English: The more indirect a request is, the more it tends to be perceived as polite or deferential. "Will you" is more direct than "would you," which is more direct than "could you," which is more direct than "might you."

Adding hedging or mitigating words is a common way to reduce directness. "Can you call him" is fine to say to a coworker you're on neutral terms with, but "can you maybe call him," implying "if you feel up to it, unless you have a better idea," might be a safer bet with someone who's snapped at you before.

Be careful, though: "Maybe" in particular is sometimes used sarcastically in an extremely rude way, as in "Can you maybe not?", or in a moderately rude way, as in "Maybe listen to me next time." Other times, as in the example sentence, tone makes all the difference.